# Using NSDate to convert a string to a date, my dates are changed to 6 months back

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an web service that spits out some dates, and in my iOS app, I'm converting UTC date to local date. I have verified that the web service is spitting out UTC dates and that iOS recognizes it as UTC.

Once i have converted my web service JSON to an `NSMutableArray`, set a break point and type `po [listOfTasks valueForKey:@"LASTEMAILDATE"]`

#### Results

> <__NSArrayI 0x157068c80>(
>
> ,
>
> 7/28/2016 2:01:41 PM,
>
> 7/28/2016 2:01:39 PM,
>
> 7/28/2016 2:01:42 PM
>
> )

Now, i do a `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfTasks.count; i++) {
    FireStormCategories *cat = [listOfTasks objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:cat.LASTEMAILDATE];
    MNLog(@"%@ was changed to %@", cat.LASTEMAILDATE, [df stringFromDate:date]);
}
```

that log spits out

> was changed to (null)
>
> 7/28/2016 2:01:41 PM was changed to 01/28/2016 02:01:41 PM **(expecting: 7/28/2016 10:01:41 AM )**
>
> 7/28/2016 2:01:39 PM was changed to 01/28/2016 02:01:39 PM **(expecting: 7/28/2016 10:01:39 AM )**
>
> 7/28/2016 2:01:42 PM was changed to 01/28/2016 02:01:42 PM **(expecting: 7/28/2016 10:01:42 AM )**

my first object has no date, the `(null)` is expected, however, this is where I'm confused. my other 3 dates are changed to a date that reflects 6 months ago and the hours should go back 5 (EST).

Comment: mm vs MM. One is for minutes, the other one for Months So it's taking the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong format for month. `MM` is used for month and `mm` is used for minutes

```
[df setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

should be

```
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

The `01` you are getting is the minutes from the date.

Comment: sometimes the answers are way to simple... ill mark your answer in 10 minutes, so prevents me from doing it now